# Ghosts in pacman maze sometimes go through walls. Is there a better way to do collision detection than what I'm doing?

Tags: java, swing, collision-detection

I am using a 2d array called leveldata to represent each tile in my maze. These tiles are being updated every time the pacman or ghosts move, with each character being a unique multiple of 64 in the array. Pacman is 64, inky is 128, etc... The collision detection is working for the most part but occasionally the pacman or ghosts will go through a wall. I'm not sure what causes this or how to fix it.

Collision detection and movement for ghosts code

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            
            //Clyde variables
            cIsRightWall = false;
            cIsLeftWall = false;
            cIsTopWall = false;
            cIsBottomWall = false;
            
            //Clyde collision detection
            if (leveldata[cR][cC] == 132 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 133 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 134 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 140 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 148 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 149 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 150 || leveldata[cR][pC] == 156 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 164 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 166 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 168 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 172) {
                cIsRightWall = true;
            }
            if (leveldata[cR][cC] == 129 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 131 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 133 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 137 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 145 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 147 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 149 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 153 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 161 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 163 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 165 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 169) {
                cIsLeftWall = true;
            }
            if (leveldata[cR][cC] == 130 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 131 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 134 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 138 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 146 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 147 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 150 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 154 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 162 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 163 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 166 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 170) {
                cIsTopWall = true;
            }
            if (leveldata[cR][cC] == 136 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 137 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 140 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 138 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 152 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 153 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 156 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 154 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 168 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 169 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 172 || leveldata[cR][cC] == 170) {
                cIsBottomWall = true;
            }
            
            //Clyde motion
            while (true) {
                if(cDirection == 1 && !cIsRightWall && cC < 26) {
                    leveldata[cR][cC] -= 128;
                    leveldata[cR][cC + 1] += 128;
                    p.updateData(cR, cC + 1, 128);
                    cC += 1;
                    p.repaint();
                    break;
                }
                else if(cDirection == 2 && !cIsLeftWall && cC > 0) {
                    leveldata[cR][cC] -= 128;
                    leveldata[cR][cC - 1] += 128;
                    p.updateData(cR, cC - 1, 128);
                    cC -= 1;
                    p.repaint();
                    break;
                }
                else if(cDirection == 3 && !cIsTopWall) {
                    leveldata[cR][cC] -= 128;
                    leveldata[cR - 1][cC] += 128;
                    p.updateData(cR- 1, cC, 128);
                    cR -= 1;
                    p.repaint();
                    break;
                }
                else if(cDirection == 4 && !cIsBottomWall) {
                    leveldata[cR][cC] -= 128;
                    leveldata[cR + 1][cC] += 128;
                    p.updateData(cR + 1, cC, 128);
                    cR += 1;
                    p.repaint();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    cDirection = (int)(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
                }
            }
```

Pacman class methods used:

```
protected int[][] leveldata = super.getLevelData();

//Updates the leveldata
public void updateData(int r, int c, int increment) {
    leveldata[r][c] += increment;
}
```

Quirks I've noticed with collision detection:

1. If the ghost is moving right and then hits a right wall it will stop as intended same goes for all the rest of the walls.
2. However if a ghost hits a corner while moving one direction then tries to move into the other wall of the corner via the randomized direction, it goes through the wall.

Comment: 1. do a truth table (https://www.google.com/search?q=truth+table+computer+science+examples+collision)
2. add logging

3. difficult to make out what your trying to do. Collision with one char to another or with one to the wall?

Comment: collision with one char and a wall. values of 1, 2, 4, and 8 represent a left, top, right, and bottom wall respectively 16 is a tic tac and 32 is a super pellet. They can be added to form corners so a 3 is a top left corner, 19 is a top left corner with a pellet, etc....